# react-slick initializes width to 0 on first page load

Tags: reactjs, carousel, slick.js, react-slick

When I load react-slick carousel into my page, it always initializes with a width of 0.

https://gyazo.com/a78362bf34a39f56802096c60b97cd06

Ive tried many things, but it mainly seems like the inline width of slick-slide slick-cloned beint set to 0 is just the culprit. Does anyone know how to force the inline-width to update?

Comment: did you try giving parent div width : 100%

Comment: were you able to resolve this?